# change the background color of the p tag to red where the data-topic-name is topicName

Tags: javascript, html, css

Write the function newMessage, which receives the name of the topic as the parameter. Function should change the background color of the p tag to red where the data-topic-name is topicName. A topicName that doesn't have a matching data-topic-name should be ignored.

For example, if the HTML is:

```
<div>
  <p data-topic-name="discussion">General discussion</p>
  <p data-topic-name="bugs">Bugs</p>
  <p data-topic-name="animals">Animals</p>
</div>
```

After calling newMessage("discussion") the HTML should be:

```
<div>
  <p data-topic-name="discussion" style="background-color: red;">General discussion</p>
  <p data-topic-name="bugs">Bugs</p>
  <p data-topic-name="animals">Animals</p>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try something? Post that js code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
function updatetopicName(topicName) {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-topic-name=${topicName}]`)
    elements.forEach(ele => ele.style.background ="red")
}
```

I hope this will resolve your query.

Comment: You have done his homework for him. At least make him show us his code first.

Answer (score 0):

There can be

```js
function newMessage(topicName) {
  let a = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].attributes[0].value === topicName) {
      a[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
}

newMessage("bugs");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function updateTopicName(topicName) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("p")].map(item=> {
    item.dataset.topicName === topicName ? item.style.backgroundColor = "red" :item ; })
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?